Good way to mark a vacuum insulated tavel mug at a certain volume?
I am going to get a 24oz travel mug, vacuum insulated (metal interior walls).  Often times, I will use it for 18oz of coffee.  I've been trying to think of ways to mark the exterior to show the height of 18oz of coffee.  Permanent marker isn't a great idea because it will be hand washed every day, so it will be anything but permanent.  Plus, marker residue will end up in the wash cloth, and onto other dishes.  Scouring the exterior wall with a Dremel tool is the only other alternative that I can think of, but I wonder if there is a less damaging way?

As I own a CO2 laser cutter/engraver and have marked my share of these mugs, it's the first solution that comes to mind. You aren't asking much from a technical standpoint, but you may not have a laser. That can be addressed by checking out reddit for private parties who may be interested to assist. I would be in that list, but my machine is out of service.
A more easily accessible DIY solution might be etching. I searched for "etching stainless steel" and one result appears promising. Another option in the form of a YouTube video provides a visual representation of the same process, more or less.
From the first link:


Surface Preparation: The stainless steel surface is thoroughly cleaned to remove any dirt, oils, or contaminants. This ensures proper
adhesion of the etching mask and improves the quality of the etched
design.

Masking: A protective mask is applied to the stainless steel surface. The mask is typically made of acid-resistant material, such
as photoresist, vinyl, or specialized etch resist films. It is
designed to expose only the areas that need to be etched while
protecting the rest of the surface.

Exposure to Etchant: The masked stainless steel is exposed to an etchant, usually an acid or chemical solution. Commonly used etchants
for stainless steel include ferric chloride, nitric acid, or a mixture
of acids. The etchant selectively reacts with the exposed areas of the
stainless steel, dissolving and removing the material.

Rinse and Neutralize: After the desired etching depth is achieved, the stainless steel is thoroughly rinsed with water to remove any
remaining etchant. Neutralizing agents may also be used to neutralize
the acidic residues on the surface, ensuring it is safe to handle and
preventing further etching.

Removal of Masking: The protective mask is carefully removed from the stainless steel surface. This reveals the etched design or
pattern, which is now permanently etched into the stainless steel.


The depth and quality of the etched design on stainless steel can be
controlled by factors such as the composition and concentration of the
etchant, the duration of exposure, and the accuracy of the masking
technique. Different techniques, such as chemical immersion etching,
spray etching, or electrochemical etching, may be employed depending
on the desired outcome and specific requirements.
Stainless steel etching allows for the creation of intricate designs,
logos, text, or patterns on stainless steel surfaces. It is widely
used in various industries, including signage, architectural elements,
automotive parts, appliances, and more.

One masks the surface leaving exposed the area to be etched. Multiple methods exist for this, including photo-resist (overkill for your project), specially formulated masking tape, semi-liquid substances such as nail polish. The key is that the etchant will not react with those materials, while it will erode the surface.
I've created printed circuit boards using a laser printer and a blue film, but that's also more expensive than necessary for your project.
Another, possibly even easier DIY method for you would be electro-etching. Another YouTube video presents the process being performed on ordinary steel and I've not found, in my cursory search, any reference to stainless, but that doesn't exclude it. This one is favorable because it uses salt water and a cotton swab and connecting wires for a common nine volt battery or similar power supply.

@fred_dot_u That video on electro-etching is interesting!  The mug doesn't have a surface that is very hospitable for electrical contact, but it's worth a try.  I'm not doing art like the person in the video, so I can probably mask the area with electric tape around the mug.  One band for the upper side of the line and another for the lower side.  Thanks!

You may be able to improve the contact by creating a scratch through the coating. If it's a painted mug, you may not have to etch metal, just erode the paint, perhaps with a suitable solvent, although finding the correct one may be challenging. Powdercoating is common for these mugs and the plastic is resistant to so many things!

I cannot understand why it is important to mark the mug from outside, but if you really have to, just fill it with the required amount of coffee, put a ruler / lollipop stick inside the liquid so that it touches the bottom of the inside, take it out, hold it against the side of the flask, and scratch the container near the edge of the wet part, with a needle or pin. You don't need to scratch all around.

I'd rather not score the inside.   Smooth surfaces are easier to clean and more hygienic.  Elsewhere, someone suggested an engraving service so that the outside doesn't look too roughed up.

The poster didn’t suggest scratching the inside.
